# Caffe's second "top" of `"Accuracy"` layer

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, computer-vision, deep-learning, caffe

Looking at the code of [`"Accuracy"`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/layers/accuracy_layer.cpp#L95) layer, I see there is an option for a second output/"top" for this layer.
What does this second output produce?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at [`accuracy_layer.hpp`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/include/caffe/layers/accuracy_layer.hpp#L39-L42), where the number of outputs for the layer are defined, there's this comment:

> ```
> // If there are two top blobs, then the second blob will contain
> // accuracies per class.
> ```

So, the second `"top"` of the `"Accuracy"` layer simply reports per-class accuracies.

Just as a side note for layer Accuracy, the reported Accuracy is normalized by the number of "valid" predictions (same as using `normalization: VALID` for loss layers).